# Python Multithreaded Messenger Simulation. Stuck on timerThread update. What do?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a piece of code that simulates a system of messengers (think post office or courier service) delivering letters in a multithreaded way. I want to add a way to manage my messengers "in the field" to increase the efficiency of my system.

tl;dr: How do I update my tens-to-hundreds of timerthreads so they wait longer before calling their function?

Here's what the code I've written so far is supposed to do in steps.

1. Someone asks for a letter
2. We check to see if there are any available messengers. If none, we say "oops, sorry. can't help you with that"
3. If at least one is available, we send the messenger to deliver the letter (new timer thread with its wait param as the time it takes to get there and back)
4. When the messenger gets back, we put him in the back of the line of available messengers to wait for the next delivery

I do this by removing Messenger objects from a double ended queue, and then adding them back in after a timerthread is done waiting. This is because my Messengers are all unique and eventually I want to track how many deliveries each has had, how far they have traveled, and other stuff.

Here's a pseudoish-codesnippet of the larger program I wrote for this

```
numMessengers=5                                        
messengerDeque=deque()                             
pOrder=0.0001

class Messenger:
    def __init__(self):

for i in range(numMessengers):
    messenger=Messenger()
    messengerDeque.append(messenger)

def popDeque():
    messenger=idleDeque.popleft()
    print 'messenger #?, sent'
    return messenger

def appendDeque(messenger):
    print 'messenger #?, returned'
    messengerDeque.append(messenger)

def randomDelivery():
    if numpy.random.randint(0,10000)<=(pOrder*10000):
        if len(messengerDeque)!=0:
            messenger=popDeque()
            tripTime=distance/speed*120
            t=threading.Timer(tripTime,appendDeque,args=[messenger])
            t.start()
        else:
            print "oops, sorry. can't help you with that"
```

The above works in my program.

What I would like to add is some way to 'reroute' my messengers with new orders.

Lets say you have to deliver a letter within an hour of when you get it. You have five messengers and five orders, so they're all busy. You then get a sixth order.
Messenger 2 will be back in 20 minutes, and order six will take 30 minutes to get to the delivery destination. So instead of saying "oops, we can't help you". We would say, ok, Messenger 2, when you get back, immediately go deliver letter six.

With the code I've written, I think this could be done by checking the active threads to see how long until they call their functions, pick the first one you see where that time + how long your new delivery takes is < 1 hr, cancel it, and start a new thread with the time left plus the new time to wait.

I just don't know how to do that.

How do you check how long is left in a timerthread and update it without making a huge mess of your threads?

I'm also open to other, smarter ways of doing what I described.

YAY PYTHON MULTITHREADING!!!!!
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using the class threading.Timer wont fulfill your needs. Although there is a "interval" member in Timer instances, once the Timer(thread) started running any changes in interval (time-out) are not considered.
Furthermore you need to know how much time is still left for the timer to be triggered, for which there isn't a method as far as I know.
Furthermore you probably also need a way to identify which Timer instance you need to update with the new timeout value, but this is up-to you.

You should implement your own Timer class, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
import threading
import time

class MyTimer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout, event):
        super(MyTimer, self).__init__()
        self.to = timeout
        self.evt = event

    def setTimeout(self, v):
        self.end = time.time() + v

    def run(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        self.end = time.time() + self.to
        while self.end > time.time():
            time.sleep(0) # instead of thread.yield
        self.evt()

    def getRemaining(self):
        return self.end - time.time()

def hi(): print "hi"


T=MyTimer(20,hi)
T.start()
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    # isAlive gives you True if the thread is running
    print T.getRemaining(), T.isAlive() 

T.setTimeout(1)
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print T.getRemaining(), T.isAlive()
```